# Converting Grails web application to offline web application

Tags: javascript, html, grails, local-storage, offlineapps

I've been doing some research on the HTML5 local storage/offline capabilities and I'm beginning to get a better understanding of it.  I've been designing a billing application with Grails and I'm just wondering if it is possible to set up a Grails application to be an offline web application, like you can with HTML5 (by utilizing a Manifest file). If so, would it be set up in the same way that you'd set it up with HTML5, or would there be any key differences to make a note of?  Also, what is the best way to implement the local storage functionality of HTML5 in Grails?   Is there any plugin or framwork available for this purpose .  Has anyone ever used this plugin/framework before, and if so, do you know if there are any guides or examples that use it anywhere that would be  really able help me get started with it?
I'd  appreciate the information on making a Grails app work "offline

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this thread on the grails user group - http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Offline-Grails-app-and-local-storage-plugin-td3824054.html

Comment: @tomas thanks for the quick reply but there is not much of documentation is available . i wanted to a  create a app in which user can create bill offline .once he goes online ,all data should sync up to the server , if you know how can i achive the above goal would be great help !

Comment: You are asking a half dozen different questions, none of which are directly related.  An HTML5 offline app has nothing to do with Grails directly - Grails is the backend, HTML5 is your frontend.  Please see the [FAQ for what types of questions should be asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Grails and Groovy can't generate javascript, unlike most languages (https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) so that wouldn't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing an offline HTML5 app, myself.  The biggest difference is that it is a single page rather than many small ones (but it might work that way if you tried it; you would need to be sure it got all the data it needs at startup).

Don't forget to add the application cache mime type to your configuration.

I never thought to look for a plugin for local storage.  In my project, the local tables (I'm using WebSQL because it's in Webkit browsers) are different from the domain classes because they have a different function; that is, they have to hold the data for the domain tables untilthe device can sync with the host.

I hope there is something useful here.

Ed